# how to make MSI file from electron app that is made by react

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder, electron-packager

I made an electron app with react, but I don't know how to make its MSI file for windows.
actually, I know what the problem is, it is because Reac app needs to run on localhost:3000 and after that electron can launch it through mainWindow.loadURL, but the MSI file doesn't work like this, and it doesn't launch it, please help me how to solve this problem
note: in development, it works fine because I first run the react app and then the electron app which causes it can load URL from localhost:3000 but when I make its MSI file through the electron packager then it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) to make an .msi file. The necessary command to build a windows app (once you've gotten your electron app set up) is `electron-builder --windows`.

If you want to use a template with all of this already set up, you can use [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template). *Disclaimer: I am the author of this template*.

Comment: Did you install electron-builder via npm?